# Issue with Customer EAV in Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento-2.2.1

I have this EAV **"abn"** which is required during customer registration and can only be modified by administrator, so no need for it in frontend customer edit.

**"customer_account_edit"** flag is common to both frontend and backend. remove it, EAV cannot be modified from administration, keep it, frontend account edit shows error **"abn is required value"**.

I can use a hidden field or hide the field with CSS in frontend, but is there a better way to do this ?

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'abn', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'ABN',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => true,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'position' => 10,
                'system' => 0,
                'unique' => false,
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'abn')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['customer_account_create','adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'],
            ]);
```